# Why the URL header takes the wrong parameter?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, annotations, doctrine

On a CRUD comment system that I put on posts, I have no problem modifying/deleting said comment by retrieving the post of the id and that of the comment. Here is the method used (which is also used to create a comment):

```php
   /**
     * @Route("{id}/create", name="createComment")
     * @Route("{id}/{comment}/modif", name="modifComment", defaults={"comment"=1}, methods="GET|POST")
     */
    public function modification(FilmRepository $film, Comment $comment = null, Request $req, EntityManagerInterface $em, $id) 
    {
        if(!$comment) {
            $comment = new Comment();
        }

        $film = $em->getRepository(Film::class)->findOneBy(array('id' => $id)); 
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);
        $form->handleRequest($req);

        dump($film);
        dump($comment);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $comment->setAuthor($user);
            $comment->setFilm($film);
            $comment->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
            $em->persist($comment);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'L\'action a bien été effectuée');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        }

        return $this->render('comment/modif.html.twig', [
            "comment" => $comment,
            "form" => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

The problem comes when I try to create a new comment. When I am directed to the form, it considers that the post id corresponds to the comment id (for example, if I am on post 1 and want to add a comment it takes me to the comment form 1). However I specified in my twig request (contrary to modify) that I only took the film.id parameter:

```html
{# Modif comment, with two parameters, functionnal#}
<a href="{{path('modifComment', {'id' : film.id, 'comment' : comment.id})}}">Modif</a>

{# Add comment, with one parameter, unfunctionnal#}
<a href="{{path('createComment', {'id' : film.id})}}">Add</a>
```

I used the same code as for the **CRUD of my posts**, and yet he when I want to create a new post returns me an empty form :

```php
   /**
     * @Route("/admin/create", name="createFilm")
     * @Route("/admin/{id}", name="modifFilm", methods="GET|POST")
     */
    public function modification(Film $film = null, Request $req, EntityManagerInterface $em) 
    {
        if(!$film) {
            $film = new Film();
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(FilmType::class, $film);
        $form->handleRequest($req);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($film);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'L\'action a bien été effectuée');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin');
        }

        return $this->render('admin/modif.html.twig', [
            "film" => $film,
            "form" => $form->createView(),
            "admin" => true
        ]);
    }
```

So the problem comes from the url which takes the id of the film and **interprets** it as the id of the comment, but I don't understand **what is causing this**?

Comment: routes starting with a placeholder IMHO are a very very bad idea. `{id}` can be anything really (that is alpha-numeric plus a few additional characters). Therefore `{id}` perfectly matches `admin`. What you can do is to add requirements to your uncomfortable routes with `requirements={"id"="\d+"}` - if i'm not mistaken. Otherwise read up on route requirements.

Answer (score 1):

In your public function, you have `Comment $comment`.
You are giving two argument to your Route: `id` and `comment`

The Paramconverter will try to find the correct Comment with what you gave him (an id and a comment). It will not check where the value comes from in your twig file.

Indeed, if your argument `id` comes from a `film.id`, the Paramconverter  will give you the wrong `comment`.

What you should do is send the `comment.id` to the argument `id`.

You can change your Route this way :

```
@Route("{film}/{id}/modif
```

For your Twig :

```
<a href="{{path('modifComment', {'id' : comment.id, 'film' : film.id})}}">Modif</a>
```